# What does "You are starting" mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality, phrases

I'm studying English at BUSUU and there's a sentence below that's confusing me.

**You are starting your journey to improve your English in our B1 Intermediate course!**

[image]

What does "You are starting" mean? I think the word "start" is an instantaneous action, it can't be in the middle of an action, so what does "you are starting" mean here, and has the action started or is it about to start?

Comment: Starting isn't always instantaneous. We say "I think I'm starting a cold," and "I'm starting to get tired of this".

Comment: Thanks. So when you are saying "I think I'm starting a cold" or "I'm starting to get tired of this", you mean the action "start" has happened but not finished, hasn't it? @KateBunting

Comment: I mean that the person is in the early stages of a cold; your course claims to be an early stage in the improvement of your English.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just wanted to know if "you are starting" here, has the action started, or is it about to start? You know when we say "I'm coming", the action doesn't start, it just has a future meaning. So is it possible that "you are starting" also expresses the upcoming future? @KateBunting

Comment: @YijiYa *you are starting your journey ...* = "You have, by reading these words, already entered into the process of your journey  ..." The continuous form, as you remark, indicates an action that has started but has not, at the time referred to, finished. The process of improving has a starting section, a middle section and an ending dsection. The idea is that you are within the starting section.

Comment: @Greybeard Thanks Greybeard, I know now.

Since the present continuous tense can express the future meaning, it seems feasible to bring the future meaning into this sentence, that is, to equate "you are starting" with "you are going to start".

Since I can't feel the mood of the native speaker, I can't rule out the possibility of expressing future meaning.

Comment: The present is shown by the "are". (The present tense is a psychological trick - it makes you think that you are already on the course.) If it were intended to indicate the future, then it would have been "you are going *to start/be starting* your journey by improving..." or "You will be starting your journey to improve..."